# How to use inboundReferences(IQL) for object search

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I need to obtain an object with the jira api "https://docs.atlassian.com/assets/REST/9.1.16/#iql-findObjects" basically I need to obtain the object with the following IQL query "Component_Type = KEYBOARD and Brand = MICROSOFT and Model = "Natural Ergonomic" and inboundReferences(Usr_Code = 40000162)"
obtain the object that meets the parameters and is assigned to the user with the usr_code = 40000162

I am guided by this document "https://docs.atlassian.com/assets/REST/9.1.16/#iql-findObjects" I am working with postman and tried the following request

"http://trtstjirfe1:8080/rest/ insight/1.0/iql/objects?includeAttributes=true&iql=Component_Type=KEYBOARD and Brand = MICROSOFT and Model = "Natural Ergonomic" and inboundReferences(Usr_Code = 40000162)&includeAttributesDeep=2"

pero obtengo este error

"""IQL "Tipo_Componente=TECLADO and Marca = MICROSOFT and Modelo = "Natural Ergonomic"  and inboundReferences(Codigo_usr = 40000162)" has invalid syntax at position 101 with error message "mismatched input '(' expecting {OPERATOR, REFERENCE_OPERATOR, IS_OPERATOR, ' '}""" "

Clearly I am not using the inboundReferences method correctly, could you please give me a hand?

[image: Este es el objeto que nesecito obtener y los parametros de busqueda que voy a utilizar]

[image: Estos son los datos del usuario que tiene con referencia entrante]

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I think query `Component_Type = KEYBOARD and Brand = MICROSOFT and Model = "Natural Ergonomic" and inboundReferences(Usr_Code = 40000162)` is wrong because the inboundReferences function has to be used like this: `object having inboundReferences(Name="John")`

So I think if you write the query as `Component_Type = KEYBOARD and Brand = MICROSOFT and Model = "Natural Ergonomic" and object having inboundReferences(Usr_Code = 40000162)` it should work (considering the rest of your query is correct jira-configuration-wise)

## Additional info

source: [Advanced searching: AQL - Assets Query Language](https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicemanagementserver/advanced-searching-aql-assets-query-language-1044784588.html#:%7E:text=object%20having%20inboundReferences(Name%3D%22John%22)%C2%A0)

I would highly recommend to use the built in AQL search UI in jira for testing queries first and then use them in REST requests when you are finished with tweaking them. You get autocomplete feature and maybe some other interesting features like the ones presented in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MiK6OJuiLk)